# Where is the Merge selected features button in QGIS 2.2?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.2

I can't seem to find the "Merge selected features" button. I need to merge several polygons inside a shapefile and can't find how to do it in this version. (I was running on Wroclaw until 2.2).

Is the Merge selected features button still included on QGIS 2.2? Where can I find it? What's the current icon for it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=merge). It's on the Advanced Editing Toolbar and it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

The "Merge Selected Features" button is now in the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar (View -> Toolbars -> Advanced Digitizing Toolbar). As @chris-w noted, documentation is [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=merge) and the button looks like this: [image: two green polygons stitched together].