# Assign raster values to a grid (polygon) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, attribute-joins

I have a few raster datasets and I created a fishnet (polygon). I tried to add the values which the rasters have in the grid cells to the attribute Table from the polygon.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of what the rasters are and how you want to assign the values to your fishnet? A polygon potentially can contain many cell values, are you after the most popular value, average value, minimum, maximum etc.. do you have https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html ?

Comment: hey thx for your answer... i have a surface elevation raster and a groundwater head raster. They both have a field with float values of their hight like 311.21. I need to get this values into the attribute table of an fishnet (polygon). All datasets have the same extend and cell size of 50x50 m.

Comment: and in the second case i have an polygon file with some attributes i also want to join the fishnet table. The polygon hasent the same geometry as the fishnet.

Comment: Joining, spatially, your rasters to your polygons is achieved by Zonal Statistics but you wont get *all* the attributes in the raster, just a statistic of them. To spatially join polygons to polygons you can use an overlay https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179602/in-qgis-combine-multiple-polygon-parts-of-a-single-feature but that will change the geometry of your fishnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With QGIS one possible workaround is as follows. First, I created a polygon fishnet from raster layer for the following image (50 % of transparency for visualization purpose):

[image]

Afterward, with the **Polygon centroids** Processing tool, I created a centroids layer corresponding to the fishnet; as can be observed in following image.

[image]

Next I used the **v.sample** Processing tool for sampling raster values corresponding to centroids for each feature of fishnet. Sampled raster values can be observed in the Attributes Table of following image for **Sampled** memory layer produced.

[image]

After creating an id field in the Sampled layer, I used a **Spatial join** to the fishnet layer, using id as join and target field. Finally, fishnet is saved with another name and unnecessary fields (different to raster values) were deleted; as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. If others are looking for something like this, I would also recommend checking out the "Point Sampling Tool" plugin. I found it very fast and straightforward to use for extracting data from multiple rasters, while v.sample was awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I could get the value from a raster using the Field Calculator, and the raster_value function. The description below takes the value from raster 'topo', band 1, at the centroid of the polygon.

1. Open Field Calculator
2. Create a new field with a suitable type (or update an existing field)
3. Use the expression:

   ```
    raster_value('topo', 1, centroid($geometry))
   ```