# Copying geometry from one feature to another feature with NULL geometry using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, null-geometry

I have a shapefile in which some of the features have NULL geometries. What I would like to do is to copy existing geometries from other features and paste them to those features within the same layer that have a NULL geometry.

Is there an easy way to do this within QGIS, preferably the GUI?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if there's a direct and easy method to do this but what I would probably do is:

1. **Edit** your layer by toggling the *Edit* icon:

   [image: Toggle editing]

---

2. **Duplicate** your geometry feature (*Copy/Paste*):

   [image: Copy/paste]

---

3. **Select** one of the geometry feautures (these will be overlapping so easier to select from the *Attribute Table*) and the *NULL* feature you want joined.

---

4. **Merge** the attributes of the two features by using the **Merge Attributes of Selected Features** tool and choose the attribute from the *NULL* feature:

   [image: Merge attributes of selected features]

   [image: Merging attributes from NULL feature]

---

5. You can then **delete** the original *NULL* features if you wish. Don't forget to **save** the edits!

Comment: Great! This works very well. Thanks for the detailed instructions!

Comment: @guyus - Most welcome, glad it works :)

Comment: As of QGIS 2.2 the Merge Attributes of Selected Features button moved to the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar and [looks different](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102766/where-is-the-merge-selected-features-button-in-qgis-2-2).

Comment: @WilliamBligh - Hmm there's two buttons. The icon to the left of what I highlighted in the red circle (and what is shown in the link you provided) is the **Merge Selected Features** button. The one inside the red circle is the **Merge Attributes of Selected Features** button :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin which allows you to copy just the geometry between features:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geometry_copier/

[image]